# Eclipse Lombok builder add new suggestion

Tags: java, eclipse, builder, lombok, autosuggest

For class with `@Builder` Eclipse auto complete (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) builder methods:

```
ResponseVO.builder().
```

It also suggests **`new`** which can't work

```
ResponseVO.builder().new;
```

Error:

```
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

Also as creating new instance

```
new ResponseVO.builder();
```

Error:

```
ResponseVO.builder cannot be resolved to a type
```

Why `new` is added in suggestion to Builder class?

[image]

Checked with Eclipse 4.9.0 version and lower

**EDIT**

It's happening without lombok's builder, if extracting generated code using inner class Eclipse suggest `new` when calling `MyClass.BuilderExampleBuilder.builder().`

```
public class MyClass {
  public static BuilderExampleBuilder builder() {
    return new BuilderExampleBuilder();
  }   
  public static class BuilderExampleBuilder {       
    BuilderExampleBuilder() { }
  }
}
```

Opened [Bug 558621 - [content assist] Eclipse suggests 'new' for qualified allocation even if no inner class exists](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558621)

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Only with Lombok?

Comment: @howlger Neon, only after adding Lombok's `@Builder`

Comment: @howlger Also with newer 4.9.0 version

Comment: The current Eclipse version is 2019-12 (4.14). If you can reproduce it with the current Eclipse version, best without Lombok and if it has not been reported yet, report it to Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger Edited, Eclipse suggest `new` when calling inner class `MyClass.BuilderExampleBuilder.build()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposing `new` after `.` is fundamentally correct, helping the user to create a qualified instance creation a la `outerInstance.new InnerClass()` (see [JLS §15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9))

It seems wrong, however, that Eclipse proposes this syntax even if no applicable inner class exists.

Comment: If I write `new OuterInstance().new BuilderExampleBuilder()` I get an error `Illegal enclosing instance specification for type OuterInstance.BuilderExampleBuilder`

Comment: @user7294900, correct, if the thing left of the dot has no inner class then you will get an error from the compiler's semantic analysis. Your initial question made it look like you didn't expect the syntax to be acceptable, which it is. To clearly see the semantic issue involved, the full context is needed, incl. e.g., class `MyClass`. Also the confusion between `builder()` and `build()` doesn't help to understand your use case.